# A Bowyer-Watson Delaunay Triangulation I implemented doesn't remove the triangles that contain points of the super-triangle

Tags: python, pygame, delaunay

Python 3.7.2, though I doubt that piece of information would be very useful.

Pygame 1.7.2. I'm using this mainly to draw the triangulation. All calculations are done with plain formulas.

The pseudocode for the Bowyer-Watson algorithm is as shown, according to Wikipedia:

```
function BowyerWatson (pointList)
      // pointList is a set of coordinates defining the points to be triangulated
      triangulation := empty triangle mesh data structure
      add super-triangle to triangulation // must be large enough to completely contain all the points in pointList
      for each point in pointList do // add all the points one at a time to the triangulation
         badTriangles := empty set
         for each triangle in triangulation do // first find all the triangles that are no longer valid due to the insertion
            if point is inside circumcircle of triangle
               add triangle to badTriangles
         polygon := empty set
         for each triangle in badTriangles do // find the boundary of the polygonal hole
            for each edge in triangle do
               if edge is not shared by any other triangles in badTriangles
                  add edge to polygon
         for each triangle in badTriangles do // remove them from the data structure
            remove triangle from triangulation
         for each edge in polygon do // re-triangulate the polygonal hole
            newTri := form a triangle from edge to point
            add newTri to triangulation
      for each triangle in triangulation // done inserting points, now clean up
         if triangle contains a vertex from original super-triangle
            remove triangle from triangulation
      return triangulation
```

However, when I run my code, while it removes some triangles that have a vertex of the super-triangle from the final triangulation, it doesn't remove all of them.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import pygame.gfxdraw
import math
import random

pygame.init()

def circumcenter(a, b, c):
    ad = a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1]
    bd = b[0] * b[0] + b[1] * b[1]
    cd = c[0] * c[0] + c[1] * c[1]
    D = 2 * (a[0] * (b[1] - c[1]) + b[0] * (c[1] - a[1]) + c[0] * (a[1] - b[1]))
    return pygame.Vector2((1 / D * (ad * (b[1] - c[1]) + bd * (c[1] - a[1]) + cd * (a[1] - b[1])),
                           1 / D * (ad * (c[0] - b[0]) + bd * (a[0] - c[0]) + cd * (b[0] - a[0]))))

def LineIsEqual(line1,line2):
    if (line1[0] == line2[0] and line1[1] == line2[1]) or (line1[0] == line2[1] and line1[1] == line2[0]):
        return True
    return False

def distance(point1,point2):
    return math.sqrt((point1[0]-point2[0])**2 + (point1[1]-point2[1])**2)

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.edges = [[self.a,self.b],
                      [self.b,self.c],
                      [self.c,self.a]]
        self.circumcenter = circumcenter(a,b,c)
    def IsPointInCircumcircle(self,point):
        if (self.a.distance_to(self.circumcenter) > point.distance_to(self.circumcenter)):
            return True
        return False
    def HasVertex(self,point):
        if (self.a == point) or (self.b == point) or (self.c == point):
            return True
        return False
    def Show(self,screen,colour):
        for edge in self.edges:
            pygame.draw.aaline(screen,colour,edge[0],edge[1])


def DelaunayTriangulation(points,width,height):

    triangulation = []
    superTriangleA = pygame.Vector2(-100,-100)
    superTriangleB = pygame.Vector2(2*width+100,-100)
    superTriangleC = pygame.Vector2(-100,2*height+100)
    superTriangle = Triangle(superTriangleA,superTriangleB,superTriangleC)
    triangulation.append(superTriangle)

    for point in points:

        badTriangles = []
        for triangle in triangulation:
            if triangle.IsPointInCircumcircle(point):
                badTriangles.append(triangle)

        polygon = []
        for triangle in badTriangles:
            for triangleEdge in triangle.edges:
                isShared = False
                for other in badTriangles:
                    if triangle == other:
                        continue
                    for otherEdge in other.edges:
                        if LineIsEqual(triangleEdge,otherEdge):
                            isShared = True
                if isShared == False:
                    polygon.append(triangleEdge)

        for badTriangle in badTriangles:
            triangulation.remove(badTriangle)

        for edge in polygon:
            newTriangle = Triangle(edge[0],edge[1],point)
            triangulation.append(newTriangle)

    for triangle in triangulation:
        if triangle.HasVertex(superTriangleA) and triangle in triangulation:
            triangulation.remove(triangle)
        if triangle.HasVertex(superTriangleB) and triangle in triangulation:
            triangulation.remove(triangle)
        if triangle.HasVertex(superTriangleC) and triangle in triangulation:
            triangulation.remove(triangle)

    return triangulation

background = 20,40,100
white = 255,255,255
width = int(500)
height = int(500)
amount = int(100)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
screen.fill(background)

points = []
for i in range(amount):
    x = random.randint(1,width-1)
    y = random.randint(1,height-1)
    points.append(pygame.Vector2(x,y))

delaunay = DelaunayTriangulation(points,width,height)
for triangle in delaunay:
    triangle.Show(screen,white)

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: For all the user who voted "to broad": There is an obvious and basic issue in the code. Everyone with experience in python should see that.

Comment: I'm not able to confirm entirely since I have to put the program on hold due to IRL events, but it should be solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't [`.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) elements from a list while the same list is iterated. When an item is removed, then the list changes:

> ```py
> for triangle in triangulation:
>    if triangle.HasVertex(superTriangleA) and triangle in triangulation:
>        triangulation.remove(triangle)
> ```

There are some solutions to solve the issue.

One solution is to create a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) of the list by `triangulation[:]`:

```py
onSuper = lambda triangle : triangle.HasVertex(superTriangleA) or triangle.HasVertex(superTriangleB) or triangle.HasVertex(superTriangleC)
```

```py
for triangle in triangulation[:]:
    if onSuper(triangle):
        triangulation.remove(triangle)
```

Or create a list of the triangles to be removed (`to_be_removed`) and remove them from the list:

```py
to_be_removed = []
for triangle in triangulation:
    if onSuper(triangle):
        to_be_removed.append(triangle)
for triangle in to_be_removed:
    triangulation.remove(triangle)
```

Or create an eitire new list:

```py
triangulation = [triangle for triangle in triangulation if not onSuper(triangle)]
```

All the above solutions lead to the same triangulation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And to add to the the answer of @Rabbid76; The method that consumes the least amount of resouces since it does not involve creating copies or additional lists:

Reverse loop removal:

```
for i in range(len(triangulation)-1, -1, -1):
    triangle = triangulation[i]
    if triangle.HasVertex(superTriangleA): #why this? -> and triangle in triangulation:
       triangulation.remove(triangle)
```

Since you only remove items from the end and you work backwards you never modify the list in a way that it affects the iteration.